# my UK short term visa got rejected. is it okay to re-apply it again?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

so i applied the 11 month uk short term study visa and got rejected by the british embassy manila.

the officer wasn't satisfied that i have demonstrated why travelling to UK to undertake an english course is more than suitable than finding a school in indonesia.

and also the officer didn't believe that the amount in my savings ( i have 3 savings, cause each time i moved to new company they requested different bank for the payslip) and said the officer doubt the savings is for my exclusive use.

i have counted about the living cost etc for 8 month english course and my savings is more than enough. but the officer that he/she's not satisfied that i have enough funds for my maintenance and accomodation in the UK while i also applied the invitation letter from my friend stating he will provide the place for me to stay while in UK.

i mean it's my choice to learn english anywhere i want. and my savings been sitting there for more than 6 months.

is it okay for me to re-apply it again?

any suggestions if i want to re-apply it again? or should i make a cover letter for that?

Comment: You can apply again but unless you address the refusal reasons the outcome will be another refusal. What compelling reason do you have for wanting to study English in the UK rather than locally? What % of your savings are you planning to spend on the trip and is that % proportional to your overall financial situation? What ties do you have to Indonesia to show you’ll leave the UK before your visa expires? What proof of the source of your savings do you have? How does your friend fit into the picture - is the study really a cover for wanting to visit them for an extended period?

Comment: so actually the one that invited me to there is my boyfriend who is british citizen. we would like to try to live together for some months before we go to another step like marriage. and i need to learn english there since i'm not a native speaking and it's harder for me understand british accent, writing isn't a big problem for me maybe just bad grammar sometimes, but i need to learn more for speaking and listening. but my boyfriend thought it wouldn't be good if we mentioned about the relationship. since we met online (we met online 14 years ago) we met 4 times, 2 times he visited me.

Comment: so i will definitely back to my country whether we get along for a long time or not. but we're not sure the officer would accept that reasons.

Comment: ECOs are not stupid. They can read between the lines of an application as well as anyone else can. Despite your not being truthful about your relationship with your ‘friend’, they most likely think he is your boyfriend and you want to come to the UK to be with him and are just using the study visa option because you hoped it would be more likely to succeed than a visit visa. The no1 rule of visa applications is always tell the truth. Not disclosing the true relationship in this application will harm your case in any future application sponsored by your boyfriend.

Comment: the reason i took the course there is that i could learn english better and have activity to do while my boyfriend goes to work. if i reapply it again and mentioning about the relationship is there any chance it will get rejected again?

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, if you reapply, another rejection is virtually certain unless you provide evidence to address the previous refusal reasons and prove a compelling reason to return home before your visa expires, for example a job from which you have approved leave of absence for the period of your visit.

The fact that you didn’t disclose the true nature of your relationship with your boyfriend in your first application will very probably count against you in any subsequent application, since the ECO may think that you hid it in order to improve your chances of receiving a visa. They may even conclude that you used deception by not disclosing a material fact, which is grounds for refusal https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF

Comment: The non-disclosure may also be a problem in the future if they do decide to marry and want to claim a genuine long term relationship.